# punycode proper email addresses

Tags: email-validation, punycode

When using an email that has unicode characters such as

```
josé@abç.РФ
```

Do you need to punycode convert both sides or just the right hand side?

```
josé@xn--ab-5ia.xn--s0ai
```

or

```
xn--jos-dma@xn--ab-5ia.xn--s0ai
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it depends if the left or right part complies with RFC 5321.

I had to reply to a chinese address and both parts needed to be converted to punycode.

Answer (score 0):

If your email provider has adopted [IDN email](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_email) correctly, then you can use unicode on all labels (i.e. `josé`, `abç`, and `РФ`). Since end of 2017 both Microsoft and Google supports IDN email: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_email#Adoption

If your email provider haven't adopted IDN email, you should use [toASCII-converted punycode labels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name#ToASCII_and_ToUnicode) only. They're on the form that you write in the latter example.

I've found an interactive converter [here](https://www.punycoder.com/); it can't handle email addresses correctly though.